# Filter on Expanded entities in OData

Tags: wcf-data-services, odata

How to apply filtering conditions on expanded entities in OData ?

Suppose I have master entity as `home` having fields

```
homeId, StateId, CountyID, Address
```

and sub entities `state` as

```
StateId, StateName
```

and `county` as

```
CountyID, CountyName
```

I need to get the home addresses and Ids with a filter condition with state name and county name. How should be the url?

Comment: Did you solve this problem? if so then plz let us know..

Answer (score 1):

Using the $expand keyword OData query should be something like:

/home/?$filter=state/statename eq 'STATE' and county/countyname eq 'COUNTY'&$expand=state,county&$select=homeId, Address

Comment: Am getting below error : 'No property 'state' exists in type 'HomeModel.home' at position 0.'

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `home` entity type doesn't actually have navigation properties on it. In OData, if you want to connect two entities, you would create a property whose type matches the entity you want to link to. These properties (i.e., properties whose type is an entity type) are called navigation properties. If you want `home` to have an associated `state`, your `home` type would have a property called "State" or something like that, and that property would be of type `state`. Think of object-oriented programming instead of join-able IDs you would use in a relational database.

Similarly, `home` should have a property with type `county` if you want to connect a `home` entity to a `county` entity. Once you have navigation properties called "state" and "county", eoghank's answer should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and i use the relational schema that links the two entities but even so only primary keys of expanded entity can be filtered or selected. I don't know how to call a diferent field that's not a primary key.
See the following question: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22047142/crm-dynamics-odata-string-javascript)