# CRM dynamics: oData string javascript

Tags: javascript, odata, dynamics-crm-2013

Imagine two tables:

```
TABLE A           |TABLE B
Entity            |Id
Id                |name
Points            |Ranking
```

How to use orderby with $expand:

```
$select=Entity,Id,Points,A_B/name&$orderby=Id asc&$expand=A_B
```

How can i order by Ranking which is from TABLE B? I've tried:

```
$select=Entity,Id,Points,A_B/name,A_B/Ranking&$orderby=A_B/Ranking asc&$expand=A_B
```

Not working
It occurs the following error:

```
:: Error : 500: Internal Server Error: The expression 'IIF((Convert(value(Microsoft.Crm.Extensibility.OrganizationDataServiceVisitingQueryProvider).GetValue(p, value(System.Data.Services.Providers.ResourceProperty))) == null), null,
```

What this means?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you would not be able to sort by field of expanded entity. You should look for other workaround to make that possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can join table B to your ODATA query by using $expand, but unfortunately you can only sort on the primary entity.

You can filter on the expanded entity, so you could potentially reverse your logic and select from B join to A, order on B and then filter on A.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2011/03/02/using-odata-retrieve-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx?Redirected=true

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309461.aspx

If you find the OData endpoint to be limiting, you can always opt to use FetchXML.  I use https://github.com/paul-way/JCL but there are others on codeplex that offer more functionality.  I wrote JCL, so I'm partial.