# Dynamics GUID to Primary Key mapping

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Scenario:

In our previous CRM system, our users had unique numeric identifiers in the form of `UserID`. From our internal API side we have only have access to the `UserID`. Our `UserID` has a mapping in the `Contact` entity. But we can't do filter queries using Dynamics Web API on `Entity A` since we don't have the lookup Guid for the `Contact`. As a result, we first make a request to the `Contact` entity to get the Guid and then use that response to filter `Entity A`.

Making two requests seems like a performance hit. What are some possible solutions to mitigate this performance hit? Anything configurable inside Dynamics 365 CRM, maybe on the field or entity level?

Another approach we're considering is caching that mapping information (`User ID` <-> `Dynamics GUID`), but even that *seems* like its too technical when there might be a simple solution available.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Andrii has basically answered your question here:
[Join and filter condition between CRM entities using Odata query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624949/join-and-filter-condition-between-crm-entities-using-odata-query)

Using fetch XML you can filter your Entity A by related contact fields.